# cURL Error in Cloudinary's PHP Upload API - "failed to connect to port 443: connection refused"

Tags: php, curl, cloudinary

I use Cloudinary's PHP API to upload images from my server to Cloudinary storage.
The code snippet I use is:

```
$imguploadres = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload([URL HERE], [ARRAY OF OPTIONS]);
```

This snippet works like a charm in my localhost (XAMPP) which is HTTP. But when I uploaded this code to my server on the Internet having HTTPS, it started outputting this error: **"failed to connect to port 443: connection refused"**.

I have searched for the solution on the Internet for some hours now, but to no avail. Most solutions involved enabling the "HTTP on Outgoing connections" setting through the hosting panel, but unfortunately I have no access to it.

For some info to help you, I use Biz.nf free hosting, but my domain is paid (.COM) from GoDaddy. I also use Cloudflare's shared SSL and other features.
The PHP script that contains the above snippet is called using JS AJAX.

Thanks in advance. Ask any questions as comments and I'll try my best to answer them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the hosting site's plans comparison, cURL is not supported on the FREE plan. Take a look at the "Server Side Scripting" section [here](https://www.biz.nf/web-hosting.php).

The upload method is using cURL to call Cloudinary's API. 
When you run the code on your local environment, you don't have such restrictions and thus you are able to successfully upload files to your Cloudinary account.

My assumption is that you will need a paid plan to get this to work on the current hosting site that you use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had too assumed the same thing, but had to be sure.